# scatterplot from 3d table

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am using this code:

```
L = {1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5};
R = {0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10};
Y[a_, b_] = Exp[-b/a]/a;
ris = Table[{L[[i]], R[[j]], 
   NIntegrate[Y[Abs[x - 7.6], L[[i]]], {x, 0, R[[j]]}]}, {i, 
   Length[L]}, {j, Length[R]}]
```

to build a 3D table: the result of the numerical integration as a function of two parameters (L;R).

Now I need to plot this with a scatter plot: the integral as a function of R, for different values of L, so, on the same plot, I need a different curve, one for each value of L.

Doing:

```
A = ris[[1, All]]
B = A[[All, 3]]
```

I have the integral for L=1.5, with `A = ris[[2, All]]`, in B I have the integral for L=2, and so on: in this way I built 5 different list, and plotted them on the same graphic.

How can I make this last part "automatic" and smarter? I tried a `Do` loop, but I cannot make the different curves on the same plot.

Comment: You can do : `res = Table[{l, r, NIntegrate[Y[Abs[x - 7.6], l], {x, 0, r}]}, {l, L}, {r, R}]` and then `ListLinePlot[#[[All, 2 ;;]] & /@ res , PlotRange -> All] ` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am here only by integrating the question with the answer by [b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gatessucks).

```
L = {1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5};
R = {0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10};
Y[a_, b_] = Exp[-b/a]/a;
ris = Table[{L[[i]], R[[j]], 
    NIntegrate[Y[Abs[x - 7.6], L[[i]]], {x, 0, R[[j]]}]}, {i, 
    Length[L]}, {j, Length[R]}];
res = Table[{l, r, NIntegrate[Y[Abs[x - 7.6], l], {x, 0, r}]}, {l, 
   L}, {r, R}]
ListLinePlot[#[[All, 2 ;;]] & /@ res, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]